# Client - Server program: send string from client to server and received respond

Tags: c#, client-server

i try to create my own Client - Server program, what i want to do is that the cliect will connect to the server and send a simple string, the server need to do some operation with this string and respond with new string to the cliect.

i found this article: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/69900/socket-programming

and it seems to works fine, i can send a string to the sever but how can i respond back from the server to the client ? (i am a new developer...)

```
Server:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using ClassLibrary1;
public class serv
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Establishing a connection with the client
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.182");
        TcpListener newList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 7777);
        /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
        newList.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 7777...");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
        Socket s = newList.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
        //Accepting the data from the client in byte form
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            //displaying the data in characters
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
        //Displaying the data in bytes
        Console.WriteLine("The byte data is");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(b[i]);
        //Sending acknowlegement to the client
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
        Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
        //Accepting data using the network streams
        NetworkStream nts = new NetworkStream(s);
        StreamReader strea = new StreamReader(nts);
        StreamWriter strwri = new StreamWriter(nts);
        string output;
        output = strea.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        try
        {
            string output2;
            //Copying the contents of the file
            output2 = strea.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(output2);
            string dest = ("C://Project//Copy//copy.txt");
            File.Copy(output2, dest, true);
            Console.WriteLine("The file has been copied to the new destination");
            //Getting the contents of the copied file
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The contents of the Copied file are");
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("C://Project//Copy//copy.txt"));
            //Encrypting a file
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            FileStream filestream = File.Create("C://Project//Copy//secret.txt");
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(filestream, cypto.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            write.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("C://Project//Copy//copy.txt"));
            write.Close();
            filestream = File.Create("C://Project//Copy//secret.txt");
            BinaryWriter binwrite = new BinaryWriter(filestream);
            binwrite.Write(cypto.Key);
            binwrite.Write(cypto.IV);
            binwrite.Close();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The data is encrypted and stored");
            Console.Write("The encrypted data is : ");
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Project\\Copy\\Secret.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        s.Close();
    }
}

Client:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class clnt
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Establishing the connection 
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
            tcpclnt.Connect("10.0.0.182", 7777); 
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");

            //Transfering of data in the form of bytes 
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");
            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");
            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            //Using the network stream to send data
            NetworkStream nts = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            StreamReader strread = new StreamReader(nts);
            StreamWriter strwrite = new StreamWriter(nts);
            //Sending a pre-stored text data
            string str1 = "goodboy";
            strwrite.WriteLine(str1);
            strwrite.Flush();       

            //Transfering of the file name using the streams
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path");
            string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            strwrite.WriteLine(str2);
            strwrite.Flush();
            tcpclnt.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a pretty good base for TCP Client/Server in C# on CodeReview here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/c-tcp-socket-server - it'll give you more insight in how things work.

Answer (score 0):

As the server, just write back into the very same `NetworkStream` you read the string from! On the client side - nothing different - read freom the `NetworkStream` you just wrote the string to.

Your `NetworkStream` objects should simply work in both directions ;)

Comment: Can i have am code example how to do it (i am a new developer without network experience)

Comment: Well you should probably read about streams in C#, the "hard part" (networking) does not need any change here to also send something back. Changes to the client: after flushing the file path (= before closing `tcpclnt`), just use `strread` to read from the server (well, use autocomplete to see the nice methods of `strread`). For the server to write something back to the stream you also just... have to write back to the stream (as the client does in the first place). Just look at your server code to see how you read from a stream and at your client code to see how you write to it. Just try ;)

Comment: What stream i need to write in order to respond to the client ? (NetworkStream ? StreamReader? StreamWriter ?)

Comment: `StreamWriter` - just do exactly what the client does to write to the stream

Comment: i added         string test = "test string";
        strwri.WriteLine(test);
        strwri.Flush(); before string output; on the server side and nothing happen

Comment: hmmm that should absolutely do it.

Comment: I can see that after i send the string from the client to the server, the server respond with ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding(); and s.Send(asen.GetBytes("respond"));